# Changing Wordpress blog name and web address

Tags: url-rewriting, domain, site-url

I created a self-hosted WordPress blog (on Dreamhost) several years ago. I've never truly been happy with the name and URL/domain of the blog, and I've decided that I want to change it.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. Register the new domain name. (Say www.newblog.com for example.)
2. Redirect traffic from the old domain name (www.oldblog.com) to the new one (www.newblog.com).
3. Begin using www.newblog.com as the new web address.

I'll be staying at the same web host through all this. I know there are lots of smaller steps I need to take in here, so I'd appreciate it if someone could help me fill in the blanks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every thing you need is covered in the codex [**Moving WordPress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) entry.

Comment: Thanks! Any other advice on what to look for? Have you done this yourself?

Comment: many times, so i can say that it never goes smooth but you'll get the in the end.

Comment: I wrote some scripts long long ago..... so I don't have to do it by hand.   Yeah, there can be some gotchas.   Like wordfence is one, it writes down the domain name some generated files, and that always dies.